# Picasso cache de imagens

Tags: java, android, picasso

Estou testando a biblioteca `Picasso` no `android` em duas situações:

1 - Ao fazer o load de uma imagem, em uma `url` publica (sem enviar `headers` de autenticação), a imagem é carregada na `ImageView`, e o `Picasso` mantém um `cache` desta, caso feche a `activity` e abra novamente, a imagem está cacheada, código:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(
    "http://site.com/imagens/3/download"
)
    .error(R.drawable.imagem_erro)
    .into(imageView);
```

2 - Desta vez, a imagem que preciso obter, está em uma `url` que possui `basic auth`, código:

```
        // Adicionar header na request
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {

                        return response
                                .request()
                                .newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", "abc123")
                                .build();
                    }
                })
                .build();

        // Inserir o OkHttpClient no picasso
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                    .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient))
                    .build();

        // Carregar a imagem na imageView setada
        picasso
            .load("http://site2.com/imagem/3/download")
            .error(R.drawable.imagem_erro)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.imagem_placeholder)
            .into(imageView);
```

Nesta segunda requesta, percebo que o `Picasso` carrega a imagem corretamente, porém não mantém qualquer `cache` dela, ao recarregar a `activity`, a imagem é buscada no servidor novamente (até que traga o resultado, a `ImageView` fica com a imagem do `placeholder`). É necessário alguma configuração extra para que o `Picasso` utilize `memory cache` quando este carregar uma imagem utilizando `basic auth`?

Answer (score 1):

É possível resolver este impasse usando a classe [Cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html), passando-o ao construtor do `OkHttpClient`. Simplificadamente desta forma abaixo:

```
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(new File(getApplication().getCacheDir(),"cacheFileName"), cacheSize);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).build();
```

Existem outras otimizações que você pode implementar baseando-se [na documentação](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html)<sup>(en)</sup>. Veja também mais detalhes [neste artigo sobre OkHttp](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Implementei isso no meu código e ativei a propriedade 'setIndicatorsEnabled(true)' no Picasso, o indicador exibido é de que a imagem foi carregada do disco, mas tão lento, que parece ter sido carregada da url.